# Interop OpenCL/OpenGL not supported, what other alternatives are there?

Tags: opengl, opencl, glfw

I'm working on a project on Linux with OpenCL. The thing is, I wanna draw an image generated by OpenCL to the screen.

In order to make it generic and platform independent I tried using GLFW and OpenGL's textures to draw such image. It would be great if I could tell OpenGL to use the same block of memory on the GPU for the image/texture, but since interoperability for Intel is not supported on Linux, what other options do I have?

I could just rewrite the OpenGL texture with the contents of the OpenCL image every time, but that's just too slow and unnecessary.

Is there an alternative to this? Perhaps a way of drawing images to windows directly with OpenCL? Or another generic library for window management that allows me to do just what I want?

Comment: Something to look at is Vulkan/Vulkan Compute. I've never used it so can't say if it will do what you want.

Comment: intel/cl-gl interop on linux is slowly coming back (e.g openSUSE Tumbleweed already ships it): https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/commit/4919c7c9fba1a2fda4b9489ceb733b4917840638

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render directly with OpenCL, provided you implement Bresenham rasterization or raytracing yourself. An image is just an integer array after all. I have a recorded talk about this on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/pD8JWAZ2f8o?t=758), and my source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/FluidX3D/blob/master/src/kernel.cpp#L85).

The rendered images are handed over either to [Win32 API on Windows](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/FluidX3D/blob/master/src/graphics.cpp#L494) or [X11 on Linux](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/FluidX3D/blob/master/src/graphics.cpp#L642) to draw them to the screen. Even if there is no screen, images can be drawn in [ASCII mode in the console](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/FluidX3D/blob/master/src/utilities.hpp#L3447) or export as png/bmp/qoi image files. This is universally compatible, meaning the code compiles and runs on any library PC without sudo permissions or any prior installation beyond g++ and graphics driver. And it works on any hardware, even data-center GPUs like A100/MI250 that lack rendering capabilities.

It's quite some effort to implement, but there is no good alternative. Libraries like Qt, although they are simpler and the executable runs cross-platform, have external dependencies so they won't compile without prior installation, which might require sudo permissions.